# Cassandra get backup of expired data

Tags: cassandra

I have a typically very huge amount of data on one of my Cassandra table.  I want to keep only last two months of data in my table for that i used TTL of two month on every data.  But now i want to keep expired data as a backup for later use case. Please suggest me what should i do to take backup?

Answer (score 0):

Data in Cassandra is stored as files on the disk.  You could just copy those files off your production machines onto whatever storage medium you would like to restore them later.  You can follow the link below to see how you would do this:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html

Comment: I am interesting in know how this is done as well. @bechbd - how does this address the TTL issue that the original question is asking about?

Comment: You asked how you would keep a backup of expired data.  Copying these files off to a backup storage mechanism would give you a backup of that data that you could then restore to a different cluster/keyspace with a different/no TTL if needed.

Comment: @bechbd -This process of copying data to my backup storage are needs to done before the ttl is being expired ,But at that time there may be a another data which i want to keep for current use . Also there is huge number of data which is going to expire on every seconds ,so how can i keep that data for backup?

Comment: @bechbd - After the gcc period is gets over the data is automatically gets removed , is there anything by which we can say that write the expired data in some json file or in some text file

Comment: As soon as you run a nodetool snapshot the data files will have a hard link created to them so the data cannot be deleted. A TTL expiring does not delete the data just makes the data invalid. Data is not deleted until a compaction is run on the file.

Comment: @bechbd  what I understand is the GC period time is the expiration time to invalid the data of ttl and on after the GC time has passed the data will get deleted in next compaction.

Comment: GC Grace Seconds states that after that amount of time the data is available to be deleted during a compaction event.  However nothing says it will be removed at a certain time as compaction events may or may not compact that specific file.

Comment: @bechbd, what will happen if TTL expired on snapshot? whether compaction will compact the sstables inside snapshot folder and remove the tomstones?

Comment: Since the snapshots are just hard links to the files on disk and files in Cassandra an immutable they will not be changed.  If you restored these backups from disk then the next time compaction was run the TTL'd data would be removed.